# how to dynamically get aws memcached configuration end point in Spring boot application properties

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, memcached, terraform

i am using terraform scripts to create AWS resources. Using AWS ElastiCached memcached for caching some data.

```
output "configuration_endpoint" {
  value = "${aws_elasticache_cluster.memcache.configuration_endpoint}"
}
```

i want to dynamically configure the memcached configuration end point into the spring boot application.properties file instead of hard coding it. 
Currently its as below

```
memcached.addresses=xyz.cache.amazonaws.com:11211
```

i am unable to find any good references online for the same.  Is there any way to set this dynamically once the resources are created in aws. I use Jenkins to run this terraform script and deploy the springboot application into AWS.

Comment: What about through SSM parameter store?

Comment: ok let me check how i can use it! thanks!

Comment: How are you running your application? On EC2 instances? As an ECS service? As a Kubernetes service? On ElasticBeanstalk?

Comment: running it as an ECS service.